# CSS is adding a border to div where no border is specified

Tags: html, css

So I have this bar with buttons on which I call a `control bar`. I want it to be stuck to the bottom of the screen and it also have the width of the entire screen.

For some reason, there is some white space on the bottom and right of the bar. (See image for more information), and I don't understand why it is doing this. I've tried removing the content of the `control bar` and entering a single character but it's still showing the same behaviour. Maybe there's a flaw in the CSS that I haven't noticed?

Here's the HTML:

```
    <div id="controlBar">
        <button id="communityList" class="sideMenuButton hvr-grow" title="Community List"><i class="fas fa-th-list"></i></button>

        <button id="joinCommunity" class="sideMenuButton hvr-grow" title="Join Community"><i class="fas fa-key"></i></button>

        <button id="createCommunity" class="sideMenuButton hvr-grow" title="Create a Community"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></button>

        <button id="userProfile" class="sideMenuButton hvr-grow" title="Profile"><i class="fas fa-user-cog"></i></button>

        <button class="sideMenuButton hvr-grow" onclick="event.preventDefault(); document.getElementById('frm-logout').submit();"><i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt"></i></button>
        <form id="frm-logout" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">@CSRF</form>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
        #controlBar {
            position: fixed;
            background-color: #282929;
            left: 0px;
            bottom: 0px;
            right: 0px;
            white-space: nowrap;
            overflow: scroll;
            width: 100%;
            text-align: center;
            clear: both;
            margin: 0px;
        }

        .sideMenuButton {
            background-color: #221;
            color: white;
            border-radius: 50px;
            border: none;
            margin: 0.8rem;
            width: 3rem;
            height: 3rem;
        }
```

Here's what it looks like:

[image: Image of misbehaving CSS]

- Might not be a border, but I don't know how else to easily explain it.

Comment: How about a link to this thing?

Comment: Try setting `body { margin: 0; }`.

Comment: You need to give the example page, so we can investigate. Your current code is not enough. You can always remove it later.

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve], within the question, as no one can debug an image and some code fragments not reproducing the issue.

Comment: Hmm, it's just that some of the DOM elements are displayed as they're database results from PHP. That's why I didn't include the code. I've already tried the `body {margin: 0;}` from another overflow post.

Comment: Getting a codepen for you now, 2 seconds.

Comment: tried setting overflow: none on #controlBar? At least Chrome shows scroll bars with this setting, no matter if there's a overflow or not

Comment: Here's the CodePen.
https://codepen.io/E_Link/pen/OqxNYE

Comment: The only problem I see within the CodePen is that you have `overflow` set to `scroll`. Remove that and you should be fine.

Comment: Ok, `overflow: none` does fix the white bar issue, however on mobile resolutions I need mobile users to be able to scroll across to view all of the buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove the overflow-scroll

```css
 #controlBar {
            position: fixed;
            background-color: #282929;
            left: 0px;
            bottom: 0px;
            right: 0px;
            white-space: nowrap;
           
            width: 100%;
            text-align: center;
            clear: both;
            margin: 0px;
        }

        .sideMenuButton {
            background-color: #221;
            color: white;
            border-radius: 50px;
            border: none;
            margin: 0.8rem;
            width: 3rem;
            height: 3rem;
        }
```

```html
<div id="controlBar">
        <button id="communityList" class="sideMenuButton hvr-grow" title="Community List"><i class="fas fa-th-list"></i></button>

        <button id="joinCommunity" class="sideMenuButton hvr-grow" title="Join Community"><i class="fas fa-key"></i></button>

        <button id="createCommunity" class="sideMenuButton hvr-grow" title="Create a Community"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></button>

        <button id="userProfile" class="sideMenuButton hvr-grow" title="Profile"><i class="fas fa-user-cog"></i></button>

        <button class="sideMenuButton hvr-grow" onclick="event.preventDefault(); document.getElementById('frm-logout').submit();"><i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt"></i></button>
        <form id="frm-logout" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">@CSRF</form>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `overflow: none` or `overflow: auto` at #controlBar, since with `overflow: scroll` scrollbars are displayed, no matter if there is an overflow or not.

Comment: Brilliant, `overflow: none` wouldn't let mobile users scroll across but `overflow: auto` works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `overflow: hidden;` to your `#controlBar`.
That should solve the issue.

Cheers! :)

Comment: Thanks for your contribution! However, I need it so mobile users will be able to scroll along the menu to view all of the buttons. While this solution would work for desktop users, the application needs to be responsive :)